# Compute the following questions

Tags: calculus

help me calculate the following function's derivate. I can not solve it by myself.

$$
q=\sin \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+1}}\right)
$$

Comment: Zanghu-Ze, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using `chain rule`. Let’s break it down into 3 parts:

$a(t) = \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$, $f(t) = t$, and $g(t)=\sqrt{t+1}$. And the derivatives of these simple functions are:

$$
D(a(t)) = \frac{D(f(t))g(t)-f(t)D(g(t))}{[g(t)]^2}
$$

$$
D(f(t)) = 1
$$

$$
D(g(t)) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}
$$

Thus we can reformulate it into:

$$
D(q(t)) = D(sin(a)) = cos(a(t))D(a(t)) = cos(a(t))D(\frac{f(t)}{g(t)})=cos(a(t))\frac{D(f(t))g(t)-f(t)D(g(t))}{[g(t)]^2}
$$

Plug into the above equations, then we can calculate the correct answer is:

$$
q'(t) = sin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+1}})' = cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+1}})\frac{t/2+1}{(t+1)\sqrt{t+1}}
$$

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Zhuoqun, do not answer very low-quality questions. Please, read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).